# Undefined reference with gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

Why does the `ASSERT_EQ` below cause an `undefined reference to Bar::kBar` error?

To compile: `g++ a.cc -lgtest -lpthread`

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class Bar {
 public:
  static const size_t kBar = 0;
};

TEST(Basic, Basic) {
  ASSERT_EQ(0, Bar::kBar);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: As you see from my answer, your question is really about C++ and only
incidentally concerns Googletest. Consider adding the language tag.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Googletest FAQ:

[**The compiler complains about "undefined references" to some static const member
variables, but I did define them in the class body.**](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.11.0/docs/faq.md#the-compiler-complains-about-undefined-references-to-some-static-const-member-variables-but-i-did-define-them-in-the-class-body-whats-wrong)

> If your class has a static data member:

```
// foo.h
class Foo {
  ...
  static const int kBar = 100;
};
```

> You also need to define it outside of the class body in foo.cc:

```
const int Foo::kBar;  // No initializer here.
```

> Otherwise your code is invalid C++, and may break in unexpected ways.
> In particular, using it in Google Test comparison assertions (EXPECT_EQ, etc)
> will generate an "undefined reference" linker error.

This explanation is rather enigmatic. (Why is it "invalid C++?") That is
probably because a satisfactory explanation is rather technical.

Even though your class `bar` declares the static data member `kBar` with
an initializer, that does not suffice to provide the data member with a
definition that has external linkage (i.e. that the linker can see), and
without one any code that attempts to odr-use<sup>1</sup> `Bar::kBar` will
encounter an undefined reference linkage error. This can be illustrated
without involving Googletest:

**foobar.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>

class Bar {
    public:
    static const std::size_t kBar = 0;
};

bool foo(std::size_t const & k)
{
    return k == 0;
}

int main()
{
    return foo(Bar::kBar);
}
```

Try to build:

```
$ g++ foobar.cpp
/tmp/ccWaEsDu.o: In function `main':
foobar.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `Bar::kBar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The solution is as per the FAQ:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class Bar {
    public:
    static const size_t kBar = 0;
};

const size_t Bar::kBar;

TEST(Basic, Basic) {
  ASSERT_EQ(0, Bar::kBar);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

As of C++17 you will be able to omit the out-of-class definition if
you prefix the initialized in-class declaration with `inline` (which
will make it a definition).

---

[1] [ODR-use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)
>Informally, an object is odr-used if its address is taken, or a reference is 
>bound to it, and a function is odr-used if a function call to it is made or its 
>address is taken. If an object or a function is odr-used, its definition must 
>exist somewhere in the program; a violation of that is a link-time error.

Comment: How can you make an static member of the class as inline. This is with respect to "As of C++17 you will be able to omit the out-of-class definition if you prefix the initialized in-class declaration with inline (which will make it a definition)." mentioned by you. Compiler throws an error for me. I am using gcc 4.9.2 version. I think 4.9.2 gcc does not include C++ 17 feature of making the static variable inline to give the variable an external linkage.

Comment: I'm also curious to see if the claim from the linked FAQ holds true, despite the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) stating: If a static data member of integral or enumeration type is declared const (and not volatile), it can be initialized with an initializer in which every expression is a constant expression, right inside the class definition